# Struts: how to use bean:write to convert a boolean to yes / no

Tags: jsp, struts

I jave a JSP with a table and a list of value inside.

One of these values, `flagp`, is a boolean.

Instead of showing "true/false" I would like to show "yes/no". How could I modify this?

```
<logic:present
  name="tabellaGenericaForm"
  property="listaLog">
  <layout:pager maxPageItems="5" width="100%"
    sessionPagerId="currentPageSt">
    <logic:notEmpty
      name="tabellaGenericaForm"
      property="listaLog">
      <layout:collection name="tabellaGenericaForm" property="listaLog" id="elemento">
        <layout:collectionItem title="form.flagp" property="Da" sortable="true">
          <bean:write name="element" property="flagp"  />
        </layout:collectionItem>
      </layout:collection>
    </logic:notEmpty>
  </layout:pager>
</logic:present>
```

Comment: Usa Struts2 (dal prossimo progetto), Struts1 diventerà il tuo tallone da killer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the logic tags, as you'd expect:

```
<logic:equal name="element" property="flagp">
  Yes
</logic:equal>
<logic:notEqual name="element" property="flagp">
  No
</logic:equal>
```

Or use JSTL's `<c:if>` (preferable).

Or wrap this up elsewhere in the business layer, or in a custom tag, etc (more preferable).